# What is the best pattern to deal with async callbacks using quarkus, mutiny, kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, quarkus, mutiny

I want to expose a synchronous API that calls an async under the hood. The async API calls my server back when the data are available on its side (if data are not available in a reasonable amount of time my API returns a 404).

I've implemented a solution based on CompletableFuture, prototyped another one using an Emitter that I store in a context that can be retrieved when the incoming callback arrives but I'm not sure to do it the right way (most simple?).

What do you think about?
Thanks in advance
Patrice

```kotlin
@Path("/status")
class DeviceStatusController(
    private val deviceStatusService: DeviceStatusService
) {

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    fun getStatus(@Valid @NotNull requestStatus: RequestStatus): Uni<String> {
        return deviceStatusService.getStatus(requestStatus)
    }
}

@ApplicationScoped
@Path("/notifications")
class NotificationController(val service: DeviceStatusService) {

    @POST
    fun receive(@RequestBody @Valid notification: Notification) {
        service.receive(notification)
    }
}

@ApplicationScoped
class DeviceStatusService {
    private val logger: Logger = Logger.getLogger(this.javaClass.canonicalName)

    data class UniContext(val emitter: CompletableFuture<String>)

    //Todo: Change for redis registration with TTL
    val notificationMap = mutableMapOf<String, UniContext>()

    fun getStatus(requestStatus: RequestStatus): Uni<String> {

        // Call async service here ... it will call us back on notifications endpoint
        // It will just reply ... your request is accepted

        val emitter = CompletableFuture<String>()
        notificationMap[requestStatus.device] = UniContext(emitter)
        return Uni.createFrom().completionStage(emitter.minimalCompletionStage())
            .ifNoItem().after(Duration.ofSeconds(60))
            .failWith {
                cleanContexts(requestStatus.device)
                TimeoutException("No reply for ${requestStatus.device}")
            }
    }

    fun cleanContexts(id: String) {
        notificationMap.remove(id)
    }

    fun receive(notification: Notification) {
        logger.fine("Notification received for ${notification.device}")
        notificationMap[notification.device]?.let {
            it.emitter.complete(notification.status)
            notificationMap.remove(notification.device)
        }
    }

}
```

The full sample is in [my github repo](https://%20github.com/patrice-conil/quarkus-gradle-kotlin-mutiny-sample)

Comment: Avoid mixing APIs, so if you plan to use Mutiny, use Mutiny and do not mix with completion stage. Async is not simple, if you had cognitive complexity on top, it becomes too hard.

Comment: You can find here a more precise description of the use case : https://github.com/patrice-conil/quarkus-gradle-kotlin-mutiny-sample

Comment: @clement is this more clear? How can I use only mutiny in this use case ?